# Should I add fixing styles before or after the original style

Tags: css, background

I always write fixing styles (styles, which fixes the unsupported styles in the older browser) before the original value, because I know, that browser loads all, which it can recognize, and then applies the last one. But somebody told me, that browser loads all, even unrecognized, and then applies the last one and if it can't recognize the last one, it applies the initial value. Is it true?

Example could be in background:

```
Body{
background-color:#262626;
background:url(projekty.png) bottom left/cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Inspiration from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Tricky_edge_cases

Comment: I think it depends. In `color: #000; color: rgba(0,0,0,.8)`, `#000` is a fallback in case `rgba` is not supported. But in `display: inline-block; display: inline-table`, browser will try to apply `inline-table` even if it doesn't support it. Or at least that's what happens on IE7.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. In my example all browsers apply the second rule even if they can't recognize the content of the background property. The output document has then transparent background (white). It depends (and is not nice) :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should list properties in order than you want them to take precedence.  Do note that `background` above is not a great example since you can specify both `background-color` and the `background` property without specifying a color.

Anyway, you want to do something like:

```
background: for-old-browsers;
background: for-modern-browsers;
```

If they were reversed, then modern browsers could still get the old browser properties.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't occure to me, that I could just use background twice, the first one for older and the second one for newer browsers. Thanks